# How to Pass Functions as Parameters in Procedures in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, function, parameter-passing, record, procedure

Is it possible to pass an object function as a parameter in a procedure rather than passing the whole object?

I have a record definition with a function defined as a public class parameter such as:

```
    TMyRecord = record
      public
        class function New(const a, b: Integer): TMyRecord; static;
        function GiveMeAValue(inputValue: integer): Single;
      public
        a, b: Integer;
      end;
```

The function could be something like:

```
    function TMyRecord.GiveMeAValue(inputValue: Integer): Single;
    begin
      RESULT := inputValue/(self.a + self.b);
    end;
```

I then wish to define a procedure that calls on the class function `GiveMeAValue` but I don't want to pass it the whole record. Can I do something like this, for example:

```
    Procedure DoSomething(var1: Single; var2, var3: Integer, ?TMyRecord.GiveMeAValue?);
    begin
      var1 = ?TMyRecord.GiveMeAValue?(var2 + var3);
      //Do Some Other Stuff
    end;
```

If so then how would I correctly pass the function as a procedure parameter?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can define a new type for the function like

```
TGiveMeAValue= function(inputValue: integer): Single of object;// this definition works fine for methods for records.
```

then define the method `DoSomething`

```
Procedure DoSomething(var1: Single; var2, var3: Integer;GiveMeAValue: TGiveMeAValue);
begin
  writeln(GiveMeAValue(var2 + var3));
end;
```

And use like so

```
var
  L : TMyRecord;
begin
    l.a:=4;
    l.b:=1;
    DoSomething(1, 20, 5, L.GiveMeAValue);
end;
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can use Anonymous Methods. This could allow you to call any function you like inside the anonymous method.

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/anonymousmethods_xml.html

Comment: Anon methods make code more flexible. However, they can be a performance headache. Don't reject them without timing, but if you uses anon methods in a bottleneck area of your program, you may suffer.

Comment: Good point.  I personally find the `procedure-or-function of object` syntax more readable than the `reference to procedure-or-function of object` syntax too. writing `procedure (a,b,c:Integer) begin ... end` inline begins to get ugly.

Comment: Your method reference uses 'Single of object' instead of just 'of object'. Are you just telling it to put the Self pointer in a Single?

Comment: @Noumenon, No, the `of object` means which  the function is a reference to a method of an instance object. You can find more info in the [Delphi DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Procedural_Types)

Comment: I actually spent quite a while researching "of object" and method references before asking, but I never saw anyone inserting a numeric type like "Single" before the "of object". What does that mean?

Comment: *Single* is just the return type of the function.

Comment: If I declare `Procedure DoSomething(var1: Single; var2, var3: Integer;GiveMeAValue: TGiveMeAValue = nil);`, how can I check if the caller actually passed a callback function so I can safely call it? Something like `if GiveMeAValue <> nil then GiveMeAValue(..);`